# Not able to setup MySQL root password using Ansible

Tags: mysql, ansible, centos7

I can't setup MySQL root password using Ansible. I get the error:

> [jumphost] (item=manikins1) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "manikins1", "msg": "unable to connect to database, check login_user and login_password are correct or /root/.my.cnf has the credentials. Exception message: 'cryptography' package is required for sha256_password or caching_sha2_password auth methods"}

```yaml
  - name: Sets the root password 
    mysql_user: 
       login_user=root 
       login_password="{{mysql_root_pass.stdout}}" 
       user=root 
       password="{{password}}"  
       check_implicit_admin=yes
       host="{{item}}"  
       priv="*.*:ALL,GRANT" 
    with_items:
    - "{{ ansible_hostname }}"  
    - 127.0.0.1
    - ::1
    - localhost
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you did not give that information, the error message suggest you are using mysql 8 with sha256 or caching sha2 authentification.

Quoting [notes on the official module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/mysql/mysql_user_module.html#notes)

> Currently, there is only support for the mysql_native_password encrypted password hash module.

You have two options:

- [Configure mysql 8 to use native passwords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/native-pluggable-authentication.html)
- Don't use this module and modify the password by your own means (script, shell command)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is unfortunatelly incorrect because the official module documentation is incorrect. The module supports modern not deprecated mysql authentication methods, but needs python `cryptography` package on the host for the available for the python interpreter used by ansible. That's what the original error message says.

How to install the the right package depends on the host OS / preferred approach to installing python packages for ansible. On RHEL 7 compatible system with python 3.6 it could be installed with yum as `python36-cryptography`.